# Rest API query with FIELDS() does not return nextRecordsUrl

Tags: rest-api, batch, query, sobject, fields

**Goal**: Get all Account records with all fields via REST API

**Approach**: Send GET request with query:

`/services/data/v53.0/query?q=SELECT+FIELDS(ALL)+FROM+Account+ORDER+BY+Name+ASC+LIMIT+200`

**Problem**: I have over 1000 objects, but since I'm using `FIELDS()` I need to include a `LIMIT` clause. I am expecting a `nextRecordsUrl` for the remaining objects, however I don't receive one in the response.

**Possible workaround**: Use `OFFSET` to get remaining objects until response is empty. This means I would be sending an additional query to check if I've received all objects.

Would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: welcome! good first question. Are you trying to accomplish something specific (data replication to an external database/backup)? There's also a [sObject Describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm) that would provide you with all fields to leverage in your query to avoid using `FIELDS(ALL)` which is stopping you from leveraging `nextRecordsUrl`.

Comment: Thanks @KrisGoncalves! I'm building an API client which will be used by multiple teams to get data from SF. The goal is to make the client as simple as possible for the consumer, so we want to return all fields and deserialize to a custom object rather than requiring the consumer the fields they want (because they would need to know how the field is named in SF).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no nextUrl because of the LIMIT clause. If you need all fields without restriction, you need to do a describe call to get all fields, which you can cache for later use, then build a query based those results.